# Building the Error amplifier circuit part of UC3843

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-limiting, error-amplifier

I am trying to build an error amplifier circuit on PSIM almost identical to the  [image: one inside UC3843]

In the datasheet, they used [image: this schematic]
Now, I want to ask in what ways is [image: this amplifier element] different than a normal Op-Amp element in PSIM.

Please note that this particular element is not available in PSIM and I need to know how what element I can use as a replacement instead.

Comment: You could use a series current limiter element; I'm not familiar with PSIM so I don't know what exact form this would take.  Note that the negative (flows out from pin) current is specified but positive is not; it seems to be typically in the 1-10mA range. Plaintext SPICE models are available for this part, I think, which might also provide clues.

Answer (score 0):

This operational amplifier has an open collector output that requires either a pull-up resistor or a current source from the positive rail. The diagram shows a 0.5 mA current source.

When the transistor is off the current is routed to the pwm comparator. So the transistor acts as a shunt to divert current to ground. The system is like a current output whereas a regular op-amp is a push-pull voltage output.

Comment: in that case, in what ways can I modify a regular Op-amp to act in the same way as this one?

Comment: so the current source should be coming from a 2.5V source (assuming 2.5V is the output of the Op-Amp)

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of the op-amp your guess is as good as mine. The voltage supplying the current source must be greater than the output voltage. Otherwise the value isn’t critical.